# How to introduce a non blocking delay in akka-http using Flows based on the request parameters

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am starting a server and handling it like this using akka stream

```
connection.handleWith(handleRequest())
```

where `handleRequest():Flow[HttpRequest,HttpRespnse,_]`
I need to create a delay in sending of response back to client based on the query parameter. I can extract the query parameter, I can't figure out, how can i create the delay using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @KnowsNotMuch answer, assuming you have some criteria with which to decide whether or not to delay a request:

```
val shouldDelayRequest : (HttpRequest) => Boolean = ???
```

You can use this decider to create a `DelayStrategy`:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.{FiniteDuration, TimeUnit}

val noDelay : FiniteDuration = FiniteDuration(0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

val createDelayStrategy : (FiniteDuration) => () => DelayStrategy[HttpRequest] = 
  (finiteDelay) => () => new DelayStrategy[HttpRequest] {
    override def nextDelay(elem: HttpRequest) : FiniteDuration = 
      if(shouldDelayRequest(elem))
        finiteDelay
      else
        noDelay
  }
```

You can use this function to create a `DelayFlow`:

```
import akka.stream.contrib.DelayFlow

val delay = FiniteDuration(42L, TimeUnit.Seconds)

val delayFlow : DelayFlow[HttpRequest] = DelayFlow(createDelayStrategy(delay))
```

This `delayFlow` can then be connected to whatever functionality you have to process a request into a response:

```
val requestToResponseFlow : Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = ???

val possibleDelayedResponseFlow  : Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = 
  delayFlow via requestToResponseFlow
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the DelayFlow

https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib/blob/master/contrib/src/main/scala/akka/stream/contrib/DelayFlow.scala

https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/api/akka-stream-contrib/current/akka/stream/contrib/DelayFlow.html

It should allow you to introduce a delay in the stream processing.